# Remove substring rows from tibble

Tags: r, string, text, dplyr, tibble

I have a tibble:

```
df <- tibble(x = c('a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abd', 'efg'))
```

I want to remove rows that are substrings of other rows, resulting in:

```
result <- tibble(x = c('abcd', 'abd', 'efg'))
```

The solution must be quite efficient as there are ~1M rows of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str_extract(df$x, "foo") == "foo"` is to test if "foo" is a substring of any element in `df$x`. It will be always at least 1, because x is always a substring of itself. If this number is higher, it is also a substring of another element, so we need to remove them using `filter(!)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = c('a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abd', 'efg'))

df %>% filter(! (x %>% map_lgl(~ sum(str_extract(df$x, .x) == .x, na.rm = TRUE) > 1)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   x    
#>   <chr>
#> 1 abcd 
#> 2 abd  
#> 3 efg
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

On small datasets this is slower (in those cases speed is not problem) but on bigger it is faster. Speed depends on how many unique groups there are compared to the data size.

```
df <- arrange(df, desc(nchar(x)))
my_strings <- df$x
i <- 1
while(i < length(my_strings)){
  
  indices <- which(str_detect(my_strings[[i]], my_strings[(i+1):length(my_strings)])) + i
  if(length(indices) > 0) my_strings <- my_strings[-indices]
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Possible improvement but didn't test:

```
setDT(df)
indices_df <- df[, .(indices = list(.I)), by = x][order(-nchar(x))]
my_strings <- indices_df$x
i <- 1
while(i < length(my_strings)){

  indices <- which(str_detect(my_strings[[i]], my_strings[(i+1):length(my_strings)])) + i
  if(length(indices) > 0) my_strings <- my_strings[-indices]
  i <- i + 1
}

df[indices_df[x %in% my_strings, unlist(indices)]]
```